# What is an efficient way to get a confusion matrix for a tensorflow segmentation model?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensorflow segmentation model (u-net) which I'm running on images with 4 segmentation classes.  (I also have a 2 class model, but the idea is the same.)  I'd like to build a confusion matrix which compares the class assignments for the resulting images.

I could do this the long way, by running the model on an image and using numpy operations to build the corresponding matrix.  However, I'm sure there must be some way of doing this inside tensorflow.  I was looking for ways of doing it while using evaluate_generator, which is what I am currently doing to get the accuracy, but any equivalent alternatives would be welcome.